# bulk resize height*width problem

Tags: bash, shell-script, images, imagemagick

I'm trying to resize all images in a directory using this `bash` script :

```
for i in *.jpg; do
    printf "Resize $i\n"
    convert "$i" -resize 336x336 "$i"
done
```

But when the resize is complete, I get `336x252`. How can I resolve this ?

[image: linux resize image problem]

Comment: do you confirm original image size is larger than `336x252`?

Comment: @αғsнιη after resizing yes, that's the reason why, i've attached screenshot too

Comment: IIRC, ImageMagick `convert` preserves aspect ratio by default - you should be able to override that (i.e. produce a distorted output image) by adding `!` (suitably protected from your shell of course ex. `-resize 336x336\!` ). See for example [imagemagick crop images to specific aspect ratio?](https://askubuntu.com/a/762841/178692)

Comment: thanks @steeldriver, just resized 2 gb of data, nearly 21k files..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the ImageMagick `convert` utility resizes an image, it retains the image's aspect ratio without exceeding the size limits that you specify.

If you have an image that is 48x36 pixels big (or 480x360 or something with the same 4:3 aspect ratio) and you ask `convert` to resize it up to 336x336 pixels, then 336x252 is the biggest it will be able to make it while still keeping its aspect ratio.

You can *force* `convert` to ignore the image's aspect ratio by using `'336x336!'` as the option argument to the `-resize` option.

This is documented in the ImageMagick command-line documentation, in the section about [Image Geometry](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry).

---

In your loop, you are using `printf` in the wrong way.

Do this instead:  `printf 'Resizing %s\n' "$i"`

The first argument to `printf` should *always* be a static format template, and the remaining arguments should be data that should be used to fill out the template.

See also: [ShellCheck problem code SC2059](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2059) ("Don't use variables in the printf format string").